# How to reference a table field in Ms Word

Tags: ms-word

I have a table in a Word document. 4 columns by 3 rows. In cell D3, I have a formula =D2-D1. I would like to be able to reference this field elsewhere in the Word document. I have tried bookmarking and cross referencing but it just appears as a zero despite there being a value in the field.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This is an end-user, not a programming question, so better asked on SuperUser or in the Microsoft Answers forums. FWIW be sure you're not selecting the entire cell when bookmarking it, only the formula field. Also, see this Answer on SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions/571051/reference-to-a-cell-in-an-other-table-in-a-word-document-from-a-field

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will however raise future similar questions on superUser.

Answer (score -1):

Having bookmarked the table, you could use a field coded as:

{=SUM(BkMk D3)}

where 'BkMk' is your bookmark name.

For more information on this and performaing a wide range of calculations in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at:

http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154369-Microsoft-Word-Field-Maths-Tutorial

or:

http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful. I have just downloaded your tutorial and am looking forward to reading through. I have found a work around which does not really solve the original problem I was having but the team I was producing the document for are happy with the work around but am going to re-create so I can practice bookmarking the table for future. Thansk again